# Can't see content (PDFs) in FTP when mounting via curlftpfs?

Tags: mount, ftp, curlftpfs

Can't see content (PDFs) in FTP when mounting via `curlftpfs` (onto a CentOS7 machine). Can anyone help debug what could be going on here? I am using the instructions here: https://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem

As a regular user myuser, tried to mount via...

```
curlftpfs 'myftpuser:myftppassword@MY.SERVER.IP' /home/myuser/custom/mount/location/
```

... and found that

1. I could not see any contents in that location after the command completed (via `ls` command nor in the file explorer UI) and
2. even though I mounted as myuser in a location w/in myuser's `/home` dir, I still see permissions as ...

```
drwxr-x-rx 1 root root 1.0K
```

... when running `ls -lh` (also not that the FTP dir should have a few GBs of PDFs in there, but here the size listed is tiny).

Trying to mount as root in a `/root/tmp/location/` does not appear to help (permissions are still listed as root (which I guess would be a good thing here), but I can still see nothing in the mounted dir as root in the terminal).

Anyone know what could be going on here? Ideas for getting more debug info?

* UPDATE:

Note that 1) I can access the share via Windows network share and 2) the full name of the FTP user's home dir includes spaces and dash (-) characters (which I currently suspect is the problem (IDK why exactly), but still testing).

Comment: Note that curlftpfs has been abandoned for a really long time. `rclone` would be modern alternative with the capability to mount ftp shares.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this a known bug. See report on [Debian mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1856966.html), and [original bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/curlftpfs/bugs/74/). Renaming folders and files prevents the issue from appearing, but of course this is not always viable.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure why / the underlying issue ATM, but it appears that the issue was due to the fact the the Windows share that I was FTP'ing into (via CorePoint FTP on top of that share) had a name in it's path that included spaces and a dash (-) character. Renaming the share to something without these characters appears to have fixed the issue.

(If anyone knows why at a more detailed / underlying level, please do LMK and I can add it to this post)